# PySide: QSettings as class variable has inconsistent behavior

Tags: pyside, qsettings

We write many PySide scripts for Maya 2015, and we save the settings using `QSettings`.  Normally we create the `QSettings` object in our "readSettings" and "writeSettings" functions.  Today I tried making the `QSettings` object a class variable.  But that caused some strange effects.  Certain values that normally come back as `<type 'unicode'>` started coming back as `<type 'bool'>`, but not all the time!

Here is a test script I wrote to illustrate the problem:

```
import shiboken

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from maya import OpenMayaUI

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def getMayaMainWindow():
    parentWindow = OpenMayaUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if parentWindow:
        return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(parentWindow), QtGui.QWidget)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TestQSettingsWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=getMayaMainWindow()):
        super(TestQSettingsWin, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Test QSettings')
        self.setObjectName('testAllMMessagesWindow')

        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox('check box')
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)

        self.readSettings()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.writeSettings()

    def getQSettingsLocation(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('Subclasses of TestQSettingsWin need to '
                                  'implement "getQSettingsLocation"".')

    def readSettings(self):
        setting = self.getQSettingsLocation()
        self.restoreGeometry(setting.value('geometry'))
        self.restoreState(setting.value('windowState'))
        print type(setting.value('checkBox'))

    def writeSettings(self):
        setting = self.getQSettingsLocation()
        setting.setValue('geometry', self.saveGeometry())
        setting.setValue('windowState', self.saveState())
        setting.setValue('checkBox', self.checkBox.isChecked())

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TestQSettingsClassVar(TestQSettingsWin):
    savedSettings = QtCore.QSettings(QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat,
                                     QtCore.QSettings.UserScope,
                                     "Test",
                                     "TestQSettings1")
    def getQSettingsLocation(self):
        return self.savedSettings

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TestQSettingsDefScope(TestQSettingsWin):
    def getQSettingsLocation(self):
        setting = QtCore.QSettings(QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat,
                                   QtCore.QSettings.UserScope,
                                   "Test",
                                   "TestQSettings3")
        return setting

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def showTestWindows():
    test1 = TestQSettingsClassVar()
    test1.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
    test1.show()
    test2 = TestQSettingsDefScope()
    test2.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
    test2.show()
```

And here are the results from running it in an interactive session:

```
>>> import testQSettings
>>> testQSettings.showTestWindows()
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> testQSettings.showTestWindows()
<type 'bool'>
<type 'unicode'>
>>> testQSettings.showTestWindows()
<type 'bool'>
<type 'unicode'>
>>> reload(testQSettings)
# Result: <module 'testQSettings' from 'C:/Users/becca/Documents/maya/2015-x64/scripts\testQSettings.pyc'> # 
>>> testQSettings.showTestWindows()
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
>>> testQSettings.showTestWindows()
<type 'bool'>
<type 'unicode'>
>>> testQSettings.showTestWindows()
<type 'bool'>
<type 'unicode'>
```

As you can see, creating the `QSettings` object whenever it is needed consistently returns a `<type 'unicode'>` result for the data value.  But creating the `QSettings` object as a class variable returns a `<type 'bool'>` result *except* when the module is reloaded, and then it returns a `<type 'unicode'>`.

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?  Is there a rule that I should not make the `QSettings` object a class variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings object has to serialize the various different types of value to bytes before writing it to disk. This is usually done when the settings object is deleted (or, if an event loop is running, unsaved data may be periodically flushed to disk).

All the time that the unsaved data has not been flushed to disk, whenever you call `settings.value()`, it will return the *unserialized* value in its original type.

It may be possible to forcibly flush the data yourself by calling `settings.sync()`, but I would strongly advise against trying this. You should always create a new `QSettings` object whenever you want to read or write values, and ensure that it gets deleted after you've used it. That should be enough to guarantee consistency.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So when I first create the `QSettings` object and call `settings.value()` it reads the serialized (unicode) value from the INI file.  If I then continue to use the same `QSettings` object and call `settings.setValue()`, it stores the unserialized (bool) value in memory.  If I then call `settings.value()` again using the same `QSettings` object, it sees that the key is already in memory, so it fetches that value, which is still a bool. So if I want to guarantee to always get a unicode value, I need to create a new `QSettings` object.